# Is there any Divine Prestige Class similar to the Abjurant Champion (specifically its Martial Arcanist feature)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, divine

Are there any divine spellcasting Prestige Classes that are similar in feel to the Abjurant Champion? Specifically I'm looking for a divine match to the 5th level class feature *Martial Arcanist* reproduced below:

> **Martial Arcanist (Ex)**: At 5th level, you master the art of combining your militant and mystical training. From this point on, your caster level in a chosen arcane spellcasting class is equal to your base attack bonus (unless it would otherwise be higher). For example, a 7th-level fighter/1st-level wizard/5th-level abjurant champion has a base attack bonus of +12 (and thus a caster level of 12th). You can apply this benefit to only one arcane class to which you have added spellcasting levels by your advancement as an abjurant champion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the martial arcanist feature is unique to the abjurant champion, and not found on any divine prestige class. I cannot actually prove this statement without listing the full details of every prestige class feature in the game—but it is 100% certain, thanks to @forrestfire, who *has actually read* every prestige class feature in the game (yes, even those) and has told me unequivocally that abjurant champion is the only class that has the ability to treat caster level equal to base attack bonus. (I, myself, could only be *almost* entirely sure.)

Do note the Practiced Spellcaster feat found in *Complete Arcane* or *Complete Divine*—that can effectively make up to four levels that don’t progress your caster level start to progress it. That is good enough for the overwhelming majority of situations.

Further, a divine variant on the abjurant champion is not only easy to imagine—as [irbian’s fine answer points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208712/4563), *Complete Mage* explicitly suggests the possibility. It also suggests that a psionic variant could work, and I can personally attest that it can, having recently finished a campaign playing a “psychostatic champion” as I called it. I have not played with a divine one, but compared to the arcane or psionic versions, a “divine champion” is quite a bit simpler and arguably less powerful:

- Unlike psionic powers, divine spells are categorized as abjuration spells when that is appropriate, allowing abjurant champion features to apply directly. This is much more complicated for psionics, which don’t have any category analogous to abjuration.¹
- Unlike arcanists, divine spellcasters

  1. don’t suffer from arcane spell failure
  2. usually get armor proficiency
  3. often get ¾ BAB by default
  4. may well be able to cast *divine power* if that BAB isn’t good enough

  That means (most) divine spellcasters have better armor and BAB than most arcane spellcasters, so the abjurant champion’s advantages in these area are relatively less valuable. (Much of this comparison also applies to a lot of psionics: 2-3 apply to psions, and 3-4 apply to wilders. 4 applies to pretty much everything that doesn’t use the cleric spell list.)

These make a divine adaptation of abjurant champion easier than a psionic one, and arguably less powerful than the official arcane version. There’s a synergy between *divine power* and martial <s>arcanist</s> “divinist,” but it’s very minor and only of benefit to less-powerful characters.

1. <sub>For my own character, I just went through all the psionic powers and [wrote out a list of which ones were compatible with the champion’s abilities](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EX40MLRQ_jetGKyVpzrmDz3xgDYuVp-Ellg2DNDvIb4/edit?usp=sharing).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Abjurant Champion itself is open to be adapted as a divine class as it says in the original class text

> #### Adaptation
>
> The abjurant champion can be made into a divine prestige class by altering the requirements and spellcasting progression. Alternatively, with a bit more work, the class can be transformed into a psionic prestige class, with its boost costing a range of psionic power points. On a campaign level, you might wish to restrict the champion to one particular organization of the setting.

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Your answer could probably benefit from some sourcing and/or quoting the relevant text.

Comment: there you are, had my doubts if it was legal, but I guess a quote is allowed

Comment: Understandable, copyright is a slippery slope. [Here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12144/60441) is a meta discussion on the topic, if it helps.